# How to create system object definition of enum of strings using OCAPI

Tags: rest-api, api, commerce-cloud

I want to create a system object definition using the OCAPI. The value type need to be `enum_of_string`, and I'm trying to use this payload:

```
curl --location --request PUT '<host>/s/-/dw/data/v20_4/system_object_definitions/SitePreferences/attribute_definitions/<attribute_id>' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>' \
--data-raw '{
    "description": {
        "default": "Enum Of String Attribute"
    },
    "display_name": {
        "default": "Enum Of String Attribute"
    },
    "value_definitions": [
        {
            "display_value": {
                "default": "Enum Of String Value 1"
            },
            "position": 0.0
        }
    ],
    "value_type": "enum_of_string"
}
```

The attribute is created, but with no `value_definitions`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in the OCAPI. Ran into this limitation too.